# Oracle loop with variables

Tags: oracle, for-loop

I have a procedure that takes some input variables with these names:

```
KEYWORD1 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD1_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD2 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD2_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD3 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD3_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD4 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD4_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD5 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD5_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD6 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD6_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD7 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD7_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD8 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD8_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD9 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD9_VAL IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD10 IN VARCHAR2,
KEYWORD10_VAL IN VARCHAR2
```

I want to loop through 1-10 and do something like this:

```
FOR X IN 1..10 
LOOP
    IF KEYWORDX = 'CLI_RID' THEN
        UPDATE FD_TABLE FD_CLI_RID = TO_NUMBER(KEYWORDX_VAL) WHERE FD_RID = RetVal;
    END IF;  
END LOOP;
```

Where X would be the loop variable. How could I do that in Oracle? DO I have to use Dynamic SQL? If so, how do I check the KEYWORD for 'CLI_RID'?

Comment: Where are value pairs coming from? Seems an odd way to pass the data. And will one of the keywords always be CLI_RID?

Comment: They are being sent from PlanetPress, which parses PDF's with the keywords built in. I do not think there will always be one with 'CLI_RID'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's really anyway to do that in a loop. You could maybe do it with a case expression:

```
UPDATE FD_TABLE FD_CLI_RID = TO_NUMBER(CASE
    WHEN KEYWORD1 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD1_VAL
    WHEN KEYWORD2 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD2_VAL
    WHEN KEYWORD3 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD3_VAL
    ...
  END)
WHERE FD_RID = RetVal
AND CASE
    WHEN KEYWORD1 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD1_VAL
    WHEN KEYWORD2 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD2_VAL
    WHEN KEYWORD3 = 'CLI_RID' THEN KEYWORD3_VAL
    ...
  END IS NOT NULL;
```

The case in the where clause stops it updating an existing value to null if there os no CLI_RID passed.